# Splitting strings in dataframe

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe, split

I have a column with strings.  I want to split and create a new column in the dataframe.

For example:

```
2022-01-28 15-43-45 150
```

I want to split after `45` and create a new column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `str.extract` here:

```py
df["new_col"] = df["filename"].str.extract(r'(\d+)$')
df["filename"] = df["filename"].str.extract(r'(.*)\s+\d+$')
```

Comment: Now it is still visible in first column, what if I want to remove it ?

Comment: Check the updated answer for an option.

Comment: Hello 
I need your help again.  'new_col' is a string now, I need to convert that 'new_col' to timeformat instead of strings. How to do it ?

Comment: You should ask a new question at this point.  Stack Overflow's format is for single question only per page, not multiple follow-up questions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71204385/looping-through-dataframe 

I have added my question here. Please help me