# Looping through dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, datetime

[image]

Hello all

This is a column in my dataframe. I need to add 30 seconds to each time and append new time. How to do it.

My solution should look like this

```
0 2022-01-28 15:43:45
1 2022-01-28 15:44:15
2 2022-01-28 15:44:45
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a Series of `'30s'`es and find `cumsum`. Then add it back to the original Series:

```
s = pd.Series(['2022-01-28 15:43:45', '2022-01-28 15:43:45', '2022-01-28 15:43:45', '2022-01-28 15:53:46', '2022-01-28 15:53:46'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
s = s + pd.Series(['30s']*len(s), dtype='timedelta64[ns]').cumsum().shift().fillna('0s')
```

Output:

```
0   2022-01-28 15:43:45
1   2022-01-28 15:44:15
2   2022-01-28 15:44:45
3   2022-01-28 15:55:16
4   2022-01-28 15:55:46
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```